# "Subdomain" after my website name

Tags: tomcat, subdomain, wildcard-subdomain

Is there a way to dynamically create a kind of sub-domain that goes between my website domain and the .com?

For instance, *www.onlinevet.com* would be something like:

*www.onlinevet**.dog**.com

www.onlinevet.**cat**.com*

Comment: technically that would be a domain, not a subdomain...

Comment: No. You would have to own dog.com, cat.com, etc..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's not possible as domains are processed from right to left in a hierarchical manner meaning that each domain is a subdomain of the domain immediately to it's right.  To create a subdomain, it must appear to the left of your domain name.  You could create

```
www.dog.onlinevet.com
```

as that would have a dog subdomian registered to onlinevet.com, but not

```
www.onlinevet.dog.com
```

as that would have a onlinevet subdomain registered to dog.com

Answer (score 2):

As John Weldon says, you would be using separate domains.  "dog.com" is it's own top-level domain, as is "cat.com".  So you'd have to own the dog.com domain name and cat.com domain name to create your "onlinevet" subdomains for each of those.

Comment: You are absolutely right, but I am not going to ruin you exact 1k rep by opvoting you :p

Comment: @Jørn either that, or we would have to find three people to upvote, and three to downvote, to get him to `1024` :)

Comment: Lol! I've been waiting for quite some time to get 1000+.  I've got 1028 now, not quite 1024 but close ;o)  I'll shoot for 2048.

Answer (score 1):

No, only the other way around.

To do what you are requesting, you need to own the domain name "dog.com" and "cat.com".

A subdomain always come before your domain name: `subdomain.domain.tld`, for example `horses.cats.com`. You can create the subdomain 'horses', only if you own 'cats.com'.

Comment: Which would be pretty expensive to acquire.